# How to replace a string value to int in Spark Dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

For example, input data:

```
1.0
\N
```

Schema:

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("value", DoubleType, false)
))
```

Read into Spark Dataset:

```
val df = spark.read.schema(schema)
    .csv("/path to csv file ")
```

When I use this Dataset, I will get an exception as "\N" is invalid for double. How can I replace "\N" with 0.0 in this dataset entirely? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I just found a typo that I write "int" in the title but write "double" in the body. Hopefully that doesn't impact you understanding my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data is malformed, don't use schema with inappropriate type. Define input as `StringType`:

```scala
val schema = StructType(Seq(
 StructField("value", StringType, false)
))
```

and cast data later:

```scala
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).csv("/path/to/csv/file")
  .withColumn("value", $"value".cast("double"))
  .na.fill(0.0)
```

Comment: You don;t need a schema in that case do you ?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Need? No, but It is almost always better to provide one.